# Difference in onload from a 'link' or 'button'

Tags: javascript, jsp

I load a form when I click a *link*.
While I load the form I retrieve values from java *hashmap*, for which the value is taken from a table.
To save the form, I click a *button*.
On submitting, that value is changed in another table, so I cannot use the same hashMap key and thereby not the same variable inside the value attribute of the input tag.

After the save happens, the form reloads with the edited values in the form.

Is there any difference between loading of these two, that is, loading a form from a *link* and loading a form from a *button*?

Comment: What exactly are you asking for ?

Comment: @adeneo edited question. Can you please check if it is clear now?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is when you load from a hyperlink **new httprequest** is called and new request from browser(client) to server is called.

when you submit form using button, it calls your form saving code and makes a redirect to the same form reloading which means it **creates httprequest** on form submission and will do **server redirect or forward httprequest** to your code for from reloading.

> **Hyper link** -> Step 1 -> Client to server -> new request for form loading
>
> **Button** -> Step 1 -> Client to server -> new request for from submission -> then
>
> Step 2 -> server to server -> forward request to from loading

Comment: +1 Thank you for the reply. Can you please edit your answer including details to find out the difference in the two?

Comment: Parth, I am sorry I wasn't clear in my last comment. I want to know, how I will find out. Using any variable or function or ...? Can you please help?